# Laravel - load relationship for multiple orders

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have a question. I hava a lot of orders (I've done this by Eloquent query) and in my model I have also relation : user. My code looks like this:

```
$orders = Order::query();
$orders = $orders->whereIn(order.id , $arrayWithIds)->get();
```

And now I want to have to each order his user name. This is relation like this:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Users::class, 'id', 'user_id');
}
```

Is there a possibility to have a relation order->user to all before fetched orders?
I know that I can do this when I have a single order like this:

```
$orderUser = $order->user
```

But I cannot do this when I have a lot of orders. I wrote about attributes - maybe this is the only way? But i wonder or I can do this only by relationships?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do here is called "eager loading", and Laravel provides a with method for this exact purpose:

```
$orders = Order::query();
$orders = $orders->whereIn(order.id , $arrayWithIds)->with('user')->get();
```

You can find out more about eager loading in Laravel over here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Answer (score 1):

You should use eager loading like this:

```
$orders = $orders->whereIn('order.id' , $arrayWithIds)->with('user')->get();
```